# Rails Active Record scope to group objects and return object with lowest date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to add a scope to my Event model that groups my events by a column then returns the event with the earliest date. Here's what I'm trying, but getting an error.

```
scope :closest, -> {
    group(:some_column).having('date = MIN(date)')
 }
```

Event.closest ==> should return the earliest child event from every parent. Here's the errors:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column
>   "events.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an
>   aggregate function

Comment: What if two records have same date which is minimum date of all records. Then you expect multiple records right?

Comment: Well it's actually DateTime, so it would be very unlikely of two identical records but theoretically, if they were identical, then I would expect two. But that's not what's happening here.

Comment: @Dinesh Actually see an error message in console (edited answer)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using:

```
  scope :closest, -> {
    where(id: Event.group(:parent_id).minimum(:date).keys)
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want something like this? You are grouping by parent_id then you are querying where id = parent_ids. Do you want only parent records every time?

Comment: I think there's some confusion, sorry. Every child AND every parent will have a parent_id. So event_one might have id = 1 and parent_id = 1 (itself). event_two might have id = 2 and parent_id = 1. So I am trying to group by all the parents, then get the child with minimum date